# Laravel - evn sometimes returning null after javascript location.reload();

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

Im having a problem where laravel is sometimes returning null for my environment variables after `location.reload();` What makes it really annoying is that it doesent seem to be 100% reproducable and i cant pin down in what exact situations it happens.

In my blade tempalte i have the follwoing code:

```
<?php
$env = env('asdfasdf');
if($env != null){
    print "<!-- not null " . env('asdfasdf') . " -->";
} else {
    print "<!-- null " . env('asdfasdf') . " -->";
}
?>
```

On first page load i always get `<!-- not null asdfasdf ->` as the result. But when i trigger javascript `location.reload();` then sometimes i get `<!-- null -->`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please be aware that `!=` is a loose comparison and PHP will perform type juggling. If you want to know if it's *actually* `null`, either do `!== null` or `!is_null($env)`.

Comment: Also, how are you setting the value? Are you overwriting it somewhere?

Comment: Do not ever use `env()` outside your config files. Good luck.